# Convert number in one base to another base in Java without using libraries

Tags: java

This is not a homework problem, I am too old to get home works :)

So, ideally I am trying to convert a number in a given base to another given base.

Can someone please share the logic, then probably I can write the code myself. Not able to find anything online surprisingly.

Comment: Like this: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/recurrence/conversion.shtml ?

Comment: You mean, the text representation of a number. The number two is the number two, whatever base you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not you can use a primitive, such as an `int` or `long` for your representation.

If you can, the algorithm is reasonably simple: convert the number in base X to a primitive representation, then convert that representation to base Y.

To convert a number to primitive, use this algorithm:

- Make a running total `res`, and set it to zero
- Go through the string representing the number number in base X left-to-right
- Convert each "digit" (which may be represented by a letter) to its numeric value
- Multiply running total by X, then add the numeric value of the digit to it

To convert back, use this algorithm:

- Make a string builder
- Remove the value of the last digit by obtaining `digit = num % Y`
- Convert the digit value to digit character (it may be a letter)
- Append the digit character to the string builder
- Drop the last digit from representation by using `num /= Y`
- Continue while `num` is not zero
- Reverse the string in the string builder

If your number is too big for a primitive, such as `int` or `long`, you need to build a class for holding numbers greater than primitives. I would recommend using `BigInteger` initially, and then replacing it with your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did not get it completely. Do you mean first converting the number to decimal ? If no then can I please request an example. If yes then Is there a way to directly convert from one base to other without actually computing the number (which is equivalent to changing it to decimal, if I am not wrong) ?

Comment: @Walt This is not a conversion to decimal, this is a conversion to internal representation built into Java (i.e. whatever is supported by the hardware, which is pretty much always a binary representation). You can go from one representation to another directly if you build code for dividing string representations of numbers in base X, and addition/multiplication in base Y. This is a lot trickier, though. In some special cases, like base-4 to base-32, you can take shortcuts, but in general it's hard.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String input = /* your input */;
int inputBase = /* your input base */;
int outputBase = /* wished output base */;

int inputInt = Integer.valueOf(input, inputBase);
String output = Integer.toString(inputInt, outputBase);
```

Comment: Maybe the person who's downvoted my answer could be kind enough to share the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

General algorithm is :

Say you get a number in base `x`. It means Σ a<sub>i</sub> x<sup>i</sup>

- first compute the number as a long or a BigInteger if too huge simply by iteratively computing above formula : n = a <sub>0</sub> + x * a<sub>1</sub> + ...
- then decompose n to base `y` : n<sub>0</sub> = n, b<sub>0</sub> = n<sub>0</sub> % y

  then iteratively : n<sub>i</sub> = n<sub>i-1</sub> - b<sub>i-1</sub> / y , b<sub>i</sub> = n<sub>i</sub> % y

And you get base `y` representation : Σ b<sub>i</sub> y<sup>i</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to directly convert from one base to other without actually computing the number (which is equivalent to changing it to decimal, if I am not wrong)

Comment: @Walt : it is equivalent to changing it to binary if using int or long type and to decimal if using big decimal. AFAIK, you can only avoid computing the number if the 2 base have exactly same divisors. Example 8 -> 16 : 4 base8 digits exactly correspond to 3 base16 digits. But in the general case, it is simpler to compute the full number.

Answer (score 0):

Is the number a scalar or a fraction?

Extra work is required to convert the fraction part.

And it is not easy to cheat, unlike BigInteger.toString(), 
BigDecimal.toString() does not take a radix.